# how to remove AWS S3 Bucket with strange name

Tags: amazon-s3

I accidentally copied data to a bucket named "`s3://my-rd-data/Project-0001`" so my bucket path looked like:

```
s3://my-rd-data/s3://my-rd-data/Project-0001
```

what i really want is

```
s3://my-rd-data/Project-0001
```

Now, i cannot remove the wrong bucket"`s3://my-rd-data/s3://`":

```
$ aws s3 rb s3://my-rd-data/s3\:\/\/
Please specify a valid bucket name only. E.g.

$ aws s3 rb s3://my-rd-data/s3://
Please specify a valid bucket name only. E.g.

$ aws s3 rb s3://my-rd-data/s3\://
Please specify a valid bucket name only. E.g.
```

Can someone let me know how to remove this bucket?

Thanks a lot,

Shuoguo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried removing the bucket from AWS Web Console?

Also, you can do `aws s3 ls` to see the name of the bucket and delete it that way.

Per AWS Docs [Bucket Restrictions and Limitations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html):

> Bucket names can contain lowercase letters, numbers, and hyphens. Each label must start and end with a lowercase letter or a number.